# display the values of a function in bidimensional graphical table

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a python function `F(n,m)`, with `n` and `m` integers, and I wish to display graphically into a table its values.

Something like this:

[image]

I must do it *graphically* (into some gui), because I need to print from 1 to large values of N and M (sometimes ~1000), and in console it is impossible to read.

In plus, for some combinations of n and m I need to change the color, in order to see more clear the values for these cases.

I wish to ask how can I do it in python as convenient as possible.

NB: This table was randomly found on google images. Its content has nothing to do with what I need. I need to print F(n,m) integers , nothing to do with sin, cos, etc. Only natural numbers, etc. Only the graphical table is relevant of this image.

Comment: Did you already do your own research on this question?

Comment: No, I did not. In this moment I print to console. I wish to know what gui to use, because I never did something similar before .

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask then.

Comment: wRAR: I watched there, and cannot see what you mean

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: No, I did not look for an answer, simply because I am pressed, and I am working with the console. I asked here hoping that some person who reads this question has already did it, and help me, and the others . I hope that I formulated the question clearly, in order to be useful for others. If nobody answers me, no problem. I cannot research this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PyQt4:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def F(n, m):
    return n + m

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/11458784/190597 (reclosedev)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.rows = range(50)
        self.cols = range(100)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table_widget = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(self.rows))
        self.table_widget.setColumnCount(len(self.cols))
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(map(str, self.cols))
        for i, n in enumerate(self.rows):
            for j, m in enumerate(self.cols):
                value = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(F(n, m)))
                self.table_widget.setItem(i, j, value)
        self.table_widget.item(5,2).setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(0,255,255))
        self.table_widget.item(5,2).setTextColor(QtGui.QColor("red"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wnd = MainWindow()
    wnd.resize(640, 480)
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe building a webpage as output can be a good solution, you can do this by printing html file in standard output or in the output file.

In the resulting webpage you can show your data in a table, look at this code:

```
print '<html><body>'
print '<table style="border: 1px solid;">'
print '<tr><th>A</th><th>sin A</th><th>cos A</th>...</tr>'

for item in data:
    print '<tr>'
    print '<td>', item['degree'], '</td>'
    print '<td>', item['sin'], '</td>'
    print '<td style="color: {}">'.format('red' if item['cos'] > 20 else 'blue'), item['cos'], '</td>'
    ...
    print '</tr>'
```

Comment: No, I need to do it graphically, using some gui. Because I need to change all the time what I print, and to change the html is a nightmare. I can already transform to html, simply printing to console, then converting the ascii using org-mode of emacs into html. This is not what I want. I want some GUI, to be convenient.

Comment: OK, But i think you can benefit html simplicity yet by serving it (using a micro web framework, like http://flask.pocoo.org/). Using gui to show in a table is not very hard, but I think you can do it in simpler ways.

Comment: Using a html is not what I want. I would have to spend time learning help tags semantics, etc.